# Restart Task on discord.py error? [Automated Message]

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I have a bot that sends @bumpers time to bump! (discord bot command for dashboard bot) every 2 hours, the problem is sometimes I need to lock down my server, so that means removing all talking permissions for everyone (raids, going on break, etc...) and when I unlock it, the bot stops, and I have to go in and restart it, which can be quite annoying. I will show my code below here so I can maybe have someone explain how I could do this!

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=120)
async def test():
    channel = client.get_channel(778166891017273364)
    await channel.send("<@$704292975978610729> Bumping time")
```

Comment: What do you mean you "lock it down"? Also you can pass hours=2 instead of minutes=120 into the `@tasks.loop` decorator.

Comment: Is there a reason why you put a `$` in front of the the ID? It won't mention the person if you do.

Comment: @Cloud it's a role id!

Comment: Ah, my bad, did not realize you could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the Exception in the code.

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=120)
async def test():
    try:
        channel = client.get_channel(778166891017273364)
        await channel.send("<@$704292975978610729> Bumping time")
    except Exception:
        #PASS OUT Without doing anything
        pass
```

Comment: Small thing, but you don't need `Exception` here if you aren't going to do anything with it.